# merging and appending hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two hashes like this

```
h1 = {:a=>[:client]}
h2 = {:a=>[:user]}
```

and I would love to merge them together but keep the values from both hashes like:

```
{:a=>[:user, :client]}
```

I tried the merge method but it remove one value and keep only one. I am using `ruby 2.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
h1.inject(h2.dup) do |memo, (k,v)| 
  memo[k] ||= []
  memo[k] += v
  memo
end
```

`memo` starts off as the value passed to `inject`, `h2`. It is replaced on each iteration by the return value of the block. In our case we update `memo` and return it, thus building up memo until on the final iteration it is returned as the answer.

The first line in the block `memo[k] ||= []` isn't strictly needed if there are no `nil` values or missing keys.

`h2.dup` is used to avoid mutating `h2`.

Comment: This answer does **mutate the `h2`**, which at least should be clarified. The answer by @Stefan is better by all means. Also, `h1.each_with_object` is better here to a) avoid returning `memo` and b) avoid abusing `inject`: `h1.each_with_object(h2.dup) { |(k, v), memo| (memo[k] ||= []) |= v }`

Comment: anyavacy, you don't have to accept a solution just because the author has suggested you do so (though you can always change your selection). imo, it is unprofessional for the author of an answer to do that. Quick selections can discourage other answers and they short-circuit others still working on answers. I don't know if you selected this answer before @Stefan gave his (which is more direct and he gives a good explanation), but I don't know why you'd prefer this one. The current voting suggests others share my view.

Answer (score 5):

Since your values are already arrays, you can use [`merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) with a block and call [`Array#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-2B):

```
h1.merge(h2) { |key, oldval, newval| oldval + newval }
#=> {:a=>[:client, :user]}
```

Comment: I would use `Array#|` instead of `Array#+` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @mudasobwa I've used `+` because the title says "appending"

Comment: this solutions looks better